# Required message is displayed even if the field is provided C#

Tags: asp.net-core, data-annotations

Using ASP.Net Core, I am developing a simple form to reset the password using email address.
My model is as follow:

```
public class EmailViewModel
    {

        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Model_RequireEmail", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Identity))]
        [Display(Name = "Models_Account_Email", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Identity))]        
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Models.EmailFormat")]
        [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Models.MaxLength")]
        public string? Email { get; set; }
    }
```

And my view:

```
<form method="post">
            <div class="uk-text-danger">
                @Html.ValidationSummary()
            </div>
            <div class="uk-margin">
                <div class="uk-inline">
                    <span class="uk-form-icon" uk-icon="icon: mail"></span>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Data.EmailViewModel.Email, new
                    {
                        @class = "validate  uk-input",
                        placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Data.EmailViewModel.Email)
                    })
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Data.ResetPasswordAction)
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Data.ResetPasswordController)
                </div>
            </div>
            <button class="uk-button uk-button-default">@Html.LocalizedIdentity("Views.Account.PassReset")</button>
        </form>
```

My issue is that even if I provide a correct email address, I keep getting the message of the "required" data annotation. What did I miss?

EDIT 13/12/2021

The issue occurs when I used a nested ViewModel. For example, the viewModel associated with my form is

```
public class ForgotPasswordViewModel
    {
        public EmailViewModel EmailViewModel => new EmailViewModel();

        [HiddenInput]
        public string? ResetPasswordAction { get; set; }

        [HiddenInput]
        public string? ResetPasswordController { get; set; }
    }
```

using the EmailViewModel above. This give a ModelState.IsValid= false because the email is null even if provided.

If I bypass the EmailViewModel and use for my ForgotPasswordViewMode, the following:

```
public class ForgotPasswordViewModel
    {       
        [Display(Name = "Models_Account_Email", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Identity))]
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Models.EmailFormat")]
        [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Models.MaxLength")]
        public string? Email { get; set; }

        [HiddenInput]
        public string? ResetPasswordAction { get; set; }

        [HiddenInput]
        public string? ResetPasswordController { get; set; }
    }
```

It works nicely.

The problem is that I want to use the nested ViewModel to avoid repeating it.

Why doesn't it work with the nested EmailViewModel?

Answer (score 0):

This is my model and my test view, it will lead to `ModelState.IsValid == false` because the input form should have a property of `emailVM.Email` but not `EmailViewModel`.

[image]

```
public class EmailViewModel
    {
        //[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Model_RequireEmail", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Identity))]
        //[Display(Name = "Models_Account_Email", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Identity))]
        [Display(Name = "Models_Account_Email")]
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "Models.EmailFormat")]
        [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Models.MaxLength")]
        public string? Email { get; set; }
    }

public class ForgotPasswordViewModel
    {
        //public EmailViewModel emailVM => new EmailViewModel();
        public EmailViewModel emailVM { get; set; }

        [HiddenInput]
        public string? ResetPasswordAction { get; set; }

        [HiddenInput]
        public string? ResetPasswordController { get; set; }
    }

<form method="POST" asp-action="Edit">
    <div class="uk-text-danger">
        @Html.ValidationSummary()
    </div>

    <div class="uk-inline">
        <span class="uk-form-icon" uk-icon="icon: mail"></span>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.emailVM.Email, new
        {
            placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.emailVM.Email)
        })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you @Tiny-Wang. I got the error when I used a nested ViewModel. EmailViewModel is nested within the ForgotPasswordViewModel which is attached to my form. I don't see why.

Comment: First, you should replace `public EmailViewModel EmailViewModel => new EmailViewModel();` with `public EmailViewModel emailVM { get; set; }`, then in your cshtml, you should use `ForgotPasswordViewModel` as the model, your controller should also receive `ForgotPasswordViewModel` as the input parameter, I'll modify my answer.